# How to dynamically set text color according to background in Bootstrap SASS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, beautifulsoup, bootstrap-4

I have a question that can be interesting for all of us who worked with Bootstrap 4 sass. According to BS docs when the parent block has class .bg-dark (for example) we should add .text-light class to HTML to get all things pretty done. 
I'm a newbie in sass coding, so I want to ask - if it possible to do it dynamically in sass file to get dependency like:

**if block has classes .bg-success, .bg-dark, .bg-primary text inside automatically is set to .text-light without adding class in HTML?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the `theme-colors()`, test lightness/hue, and then extend `text-light` as needed...

```
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
    @if ((lightness($value)) < 60 and (hue($value)) > 45) {
        .bg-#{$color} {
            @extend .text-light
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo on Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/jg5SSboTys)

Answer (score 1):

In your custom SASS file simply [extend](https://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/) the`.text-light` class inside the other classes

```
.bg-success, .bg-dark, .bg-primary {
  @extend .text-light
}
```

Note : Make sure you have included Bootstrap SASS file in your custom SASS file.

Comment: Oh my god, so simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

Great! What I needed! You suggest to get text-color from lightness. But I have a slightly another approach. I use variants of color:

```
<code>$color-variants: ( 100: -10%,
200: -25%,
300: -50%,
400: -75%,
500: 100%,
600: 75%,
700: 50%,
800: 25%,
900: 15%);
//  Add color variants to $colors
@each $color-name,
$color in $colors {
    @each $variant-name,
    $percent in $color-variants {
        $mix-color: if($percent < 0%, white, black);
        $colors: map-merge($colors, ($color-name+'-'+$variant-name: mix($color, $mix-color, abs($percent))));
    }
}
}
</code>
```

In that case, how can I work with that? For example if 
.bg-******-300 text should be .text-dark, 
if .bg-*****-900 text should be .text-light?

Comment: Please edit and add this to the question.  Not as an answer.